# Android: How to get alarmID after the set unique alarm?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I'm trying to insert new unique alarm via following code:

```
public static Long setUniqueAlarm(Reminder reminder, Integer year, int month, Integer day,
                                      Integer hour, Integer minute, Context context) {
        Log.d("ALARMHELPER", "Year: " + year + ", month: " + month + ", day: " + day +
                ", hour: " + hour + ", minute: " + minute);
        Long alarmId = null;
        try {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0, 0);
//            DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 11, 27, 18, 11, 0, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
            // Pass the intent type and other additional values
            alarmIntent.putExtra(Constants.Global.ALARM_TYPE, Constants.Global.ALARM_TYPE_UNIQUE);
            alarmIntent.putExtra(Constants.Global.ALARM_CATEGORY, reminder.getConditionDescription());
            alarmIntent.putExtra(Constants.Global.ALARM_DESCRIPTION, reminder.getConditionDescription());
            int id = (int)DatabaseHelper.getHighestAlarmId();
            PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, alarmIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dt.getMillis(), pendingAlarmIntent);
            // Save alarm item to DB too.
            // TODO: Remove alarms (table, model) before the production version
            //saveAlarmToDb(reminder, dt.toString(), id, context);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Logger.e(e.getMessage());
        }

        return alarmId;
    }
```

Because is need to cancel alarms programatically i need to get their values after the new alarm is added.

Is possible to get unique ID of the alarm and cancel alarm by this ID?

Or should i generate unique ID and save ID into extra ? (it means)

```
alarmIntent.putExtra("uniqueID", 1234556);
```

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: getIntent()getExtra("uniqueID");

Comment: But i must generate this ID and i cannot cancel alarm by this ID.